# Java bean class

Tags: java

Bean class /encapsulation means variable should be private & getter & setter should be public. Because of the reason data hiding.Anybody can't access this variable out side.

My Question is :`With the getter/setter method we can access/set variable from outside class.Then why we need to keep that variable private && how we can tell this is data-hiding?

Actually i like to get some explanation because , without any idea just i am doing project like this.
Please if there are any mistake or unclear question, please forgive me.

Please anybody explain this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: silly example: your variable could be an `int`, but you could get and set a `String` value parsing it... in a transparent/incapsulated way

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Setter and Getter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207994/java-setter-and-getter)

Comment: We can using `setter/getter` as filter concept. For example if you want authorize anyone that call `setter`, you do this task into setter method.

Answer (score 2):

Few reasons I just thought about:

1. you control how a variable is being accessed, for example by not allowing invalid values like `null` to be set in the `setter` or even not allowing a setter at all for read only variables.
2. you can change the structure of the variable e.g. its data type and keep the `setter` and `getter` definitions without any change, so it is easier for you to do internal change/refactoring without affecting all the users of the class.

Answer (score 1):

The getter / setter define a readable / writeable (or both) property of the class.
The private field declares one possible internal representation of this property.

By using a property definition (getter and setter) you can define the access to this field or you can add constraints on the setter. In case of collections you can ensure to provide only an unmodifiable Versions.

Also you are able to delegate to delegate the value retrival to another class or object during refactoring without changing the collaborating objects. You are able to change the internal datatype, e.g. build data classes too.

So you encapsulate the internal state and provide access.

Remember not everey field needs getter and setter ;-)

Answer (score 1):

1) By doing so, you are actually exposing the variables value but it encapsulates the way the value of the variable is calculated. With this, you can change the way the value of variable is calculated at any point of time, according to your requirement.

2) This way of representation helps "[Transfer Object](http://www.javacamp.org/designPattern/transferobj.html)" Design pattern. What it says is that you can mold all the variables into single object and send it to client rather than sending each attribute value, every time when client asks for one.